# GREP: Find the locations where 2 words co-exist in a list of strings

Tags: r

Given the list below:

```
list <- c("Horse Cat - Dog - Snake/Cow", "Monkey  Chicken - Horse - Donkey/Cow", "Fish Rat - Tortoise - Worm/Bird", "Bat Lizard - Ox - Snake/Cow",
          "Dog Cat - Horse - Snake/Cow")
```

What is the best method for finding the locations where Horse and Cow both exist in the same string?

Trying: `grepl("Horse & Cow", list)` gives me: `[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`

How can I write a grep statement which returns `[1] TRUE TRUE FALSE FALSE TRUE` ?

Comment: Maybe with the `&` outside. `grepl("Horse", list) & grepl("Cow", list)`
Or maybe more flexible depending on your application:
`pattern = c("Horse", "Cow")`
`Reduce(\`&\`, lapply(pattern, grepl, list))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try achieving this using regex, this seem to work

```
grepl("Horse.*?Cow|Cow.*?Horse", list)
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

In case you want to ignore cases, you could add `ignore.case = TRUE`

Btw, if you want the locations, it's probably better to use `grep` instead as in

```
grep("Horse.*?Cow|Cow.*?Horse", list)
## [1] 1 2 5
```

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is just to use two `grepl` and combine with `&`

```
R> grepl("Horse", list) & grepl("Cow", list)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

since

```
R> grepl("Horse", list)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
R> grepl("Cow", list)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

---

Alternatively, you could use a single `grepl` command:

```
grepl("Cow.*Horse|Horse.*Cow", list)
```

Answer (score 1):

To return a logical vector, you can use:

```
grepl("Horse", list) & grepl("Cow", list)
```

To return the indices, wrap the above statement in `which()`

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility:

```
grepl("^(?=.*\\bHorse\\b)(?=.*\\bCow\\b)", list, perl=TRUE) 
## [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Though:

```
grepl("^(?=.*\\bhorse\\b)(?=.*\\bcow\\b)", list, ignore.case=TRUE, perl=TRUE)
```

may be more useful when case can vary.